# Is good to use TypeORM entity models classes in conjuction with NestJS-GraphQL schema type?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, dry, typeorm

I'm creating a [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) API using [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) and [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/). Starting with the classic User entity I've created both the `user.type.ts` and the `user.entity.ts` as described by the Nestjs documentation.

This is an example of the content:

- `user.entity.ts`

```js
@Entity({ schema: 'mydb', name: 'userList' })
export class User {

    @Column('varchar', { name: 'guid', unique: true, length: 36 })
    guid: string;

    @Column('varchar', { name: 'firstName', length: 50 })
    firstName: string;

    @Column('varchar', { name: 'lastName', length: 100 })
    lastName: string;

    // ...
```

- `user.type.ts`

```js
@ObjectType()
export class UserType {
  @Field({
    name: 'ID',
    description: 'Global Universal ID of the User',
  })
  guid: string;

  @Field()
  firstName: string;

  @Field()
  lastName: string;

  // ...
```

The question is: since they use the same fields, can I create a single class that combines the decorators of both classes?

For instance:

```js
@Entity({ schema: 'mydb', name: 'userList' })
@ObjectType()
export class User {

    @Column('varchar', { name: 'guid', unique: true, length: 36 })
    @Field({
      name: 'ID',
      description: 'Global Universal ID of the User',
    })
    guid: string;

    @Field()
    @Column('varchar', { name: 'firstName', length: 50 })
    firstName: string;

    @Field()
    @Column('varchar', { name: 'lastName', length: 100 })
    lastName: string;
```

Is it an antipattern? are there any limitations or downsides in doing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you are proposing. It isn't a problem. And it is a personal preference to do so.

However, you'll probably quickly learn as I have that despite the two having the same shape from a data structure perspective, the entity and the GraphQL object (or in NestJS terms, the Data Transfer Object or DTO) do have different purposes. You'll also find in some situations the need to convert from one to the other and to do so will require them to be separate.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I've been using the DTO with REST, but in graphql I think they are useless since the field mapping and the validations are done by graphql. Moreover, for the arguments of the queries/mutations I'm using a separated class. The mixed class I'm referring above would be used only for the gql payload and I can easily hide/transform/extends fields with the graphl decorators. For now I really don't see the point of keeping them separated. Could you give me a real-world example?

Comment: @Joseph - One great example I can name is when your API field name should be different than your database's field name. If you build the entity and GraphQL object together, you are stuck with the api name and entity field names having to be the same. Might not seem like an issue, but it can be.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was thinking the same but actually with the @Field decorator on Nestjs you can define the mapping of a field name. For instance: `@Field({name: ID}) guid: string;` it means that your db field is called guid but it's exposed as ID. Also you can @HideField and stuff like that. For now I don't see limitation but I'll try to spot them as well

Answer (score 2):

I have the case where the Entities don't match the objects precisely.
I have orders with products, but I only store the productId and resolve the product data fresh from a different system.

Here I think it makes more sense to separate the two for type safety.
I don't get the real product {} object back, only the productId, but typescript thinks I have both there.